# How to echo <script> in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to display output from following code. The script ish creating cookie policy pop-up.

```
<?php
    if (some statement) {
    echo '<script> long script here </script>';
    } else {
    echo '<script> some other script </script>';
} ?>
```

I am definitely making some syntax mistake in `echo '<script></script>';` part, because if statement itself is working (I am able to echo simple `<h1><h1>` text. And the script itself is also working.

I have tried with `echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">';` and also

```
echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">';
echo '[script here]';
echo '</script>';
```

I dont't get any errors. Simply nothing shows up.

Comment: `</stript>` will not work, spelling matters in programming

Comment: the mistake was only here (in the post), not in the code, corrected already

Comment: why do it like that anyway? why not close the `PHP IF` before the script and open after?

Comment: View source and check your browser's error console. My suspicion is the script is outputting just fine, but the specific code in the script tags - which you've censored or omitted - isn't working.

Comment: I don't get any errors and as I wrote before, script itself is working just fine

Comment: When you say "nothing shows up", what do you expect to show up, and where? The code you've given is so incomplete that it's impossible to tell what you're actually doing.

Comment: Edited. The script is cerating cookie policy popup. It is working properly. But the popup is not showing up  when put in the if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break out of PHP, or dont put clientside scripting inside serverside echos, instead abstract that code to clientside.

```
<?php if (some statement) {?>
<script> long script here </script>
<?php } else { ?>
<script> some other script </script>
<?php } ?>
```